# Using vuex getters in computed property

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am sending props from component 1 to component 2. If component 2 is called the start- and end time is set. The computed properties in component 2 are accessing some getters in my vuex store. In this store
I call some other getters. This all works.

The problem is that I am not satisfied with the solution. The getters in the vuex store always have to filter the same things, e.g when I call the getter `getAllBookingsForBookingNumber` from `getStartTime` and `getEndTime`. For that results all courts have to be filtered first. I guess you see the problem...

Is there maybe a more efficient way to do it?

**Component 1:**

```
        <app-book-info v-bind:courtId="selectedCourtId"
                       v-bind:slotId="selectedSlotId">
        </app-book-info>´
```

**Component 2:**

```
    <template>..{{ getStartTime }}...</template>
    props: {
        courtId: {
            type: Number,
            default: 1,
        },
        slotId: {
            type: Number,
            default: 1
        }
    },
    computed: {
        getStartTime() {
            return this.$store.getters.getStartTime(this.courtId, this.slotId);
        },
        getEndTime() {
            return this.$store.getters.getEndTime(this.courtId, this.slotId);
        }
```

**store.js**

```
    getters: {
        getStartTime: (state, getters) => (courtId, slotId) => {
           return getters.getAllBookingsForBookingNumber(courtId, slotId)[0].time;
        },
        getEndTime: (state, getters) => (courtId, slotId) => {
           let allBookings = getters.getAllBookingsForBookingNumber(courtId, slotId);
           let length = allBookings.length;
           return allBookings[length - 1].time;
        },
        getBookingNumber: (state, getters) => (courtId, slotId) => {
           return getters.getCourt(courtId)[0].slots.filter(slot => slot.id === slotId) 
          [0].bookingNumber;
        },
        getAllBookingsForBookingNumber: (state, getters) => (courtId, slotId) => {
           return getters.getCourt(courtId)[0].slots.filter(slot => slot.bookingNumber === 
           getters.getBookingNumber(courtId, slotId));
        }
   }
```

Comment: As a general tip, it seems you might be using arrays where objects would be better.  If possible, use an object hash whose keys are the id numbers if you intend to look up data by id.

Comment: Computed properties are cached and reactive, which means the filter should not get recalculated unless your data changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I do not understand how to use objects instead of an array. Maybe you could give me a hint how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Speaking of cache, these getters will *not* be cached, since they are [method-style access](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access).  Using a Vuex state object hash is pretty simple, ex.: `state.bookings = {};  state.bookings[1] = [{ booking data for #1 in here }, { more #1 booking data }]`. In other words, you'd store booking data in a state object instead of using getters.